# how to query from python dictionary ?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am tying to replace a small sql database with a dictionary. The only one problem I am facing is with query. Its just becoming so complicated. here is the example:

```
foo={'id_1': {'location': 'location_1', 'material': 'A'},
     'id_2': {'location': 'location_1', 'material': 'A'},
     'id_3': {'location': 'location_1', 'material': 'B'},
     'id_4': {'location': 'location_2', 'material': 'B'},
     'id_5': {'location': 'location_2', 'material': 'A'},
     'id_6': {'location': 'location_1', 'material': 'C'},
     'id_7': {'location': 'location_1', 'material': 'A'},
     'id_8': {'location': 'location_2', 'material': 'B'}}
```

So, I wanted to to some query based on locations and the result should look like this:

```
{'location_1' : {'A': 3, 'B': 1, 'C': 1}, 'location_2': {'A':1,'B':2}}
```

Is there any way to do query on python dictionary? Or at least neat way of doing it ?

Thanks

Comment: And what do you mean by "query"?

Comment: Not as easily as you can in a small SQL database. Why'd you want to replace it?

Comment: a `dict` is not a relational database.  Either you do a "query" via a key, or you loop over the whole thing looking for what you want.

Comment: read: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: @elParaguayo I tried to loop and create new dictionary.

Comment: @Wooble, I am trying to do some memory management.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to use a [`defaultdict()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and [`Counter()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) object to achieve what you want:

```
results = defaultdict(Counter)
for entry in foo.values():
    results[entry['location']][entry['material']] += 1
```

which produces:

```
defaultdict(<class 'collections.Counter'>, {
    'location_2': Counter({'B': 2, 'A': 1}),
    'location_1': Counter({'A': 3, 'C': 1, 'B': 1})
})
```

but using an actual database (such as the bundled [`sqlite3`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html)) would be far more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
d = {}
for k,v in foo.iteritems():
    loc = v['location']
    mat = v['material']
    d.setdefault(loc, {})
    d[loc].setdefault(mat, 0)
    d[loc][mat] = d[loc].get(mat, 0) + 1
print d
```

Output:

```
{'location_2': {'A': 1, 'B': 2}, 'location_1': {'A': 3, 'C': 1, 'B': 1}}
```